# Getting Distinct Count from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

I have two tables for example 
table1 as

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║    id    ║ login_id   ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║          2 ║
║        2 ║          2 ║
║        3 ║          2 ║
║        4 ║          1 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

and table2 as

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║    id2   ║ login_id   ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║          3 ║
║        2 ║          1 ║
║        3 ║          2 ║
║        4 ║          1 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

I need to get the count of column login_id from the two tables where there is no duplicate

I have tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.login_id), COUNT(DISTINCT t2.login_id) FROM table1 as t1 JOIN table2 AS t2
```

I got 
COUNT(DISTINCT t1.login_id) 2
COUNT(DISTINCT t2.login_id) 3.

Is there any way that I can the output to be only 3. 
Hope that it's clear to understand what I want.

Comment: nice ascii-work I must say.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION`  :

```
select count(*)
from (select login_id 
      from table1 union -- WILL REMOVE DUPLICATE
      select login_id 
      from table2
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select count(distinct login_id) no_distinct_logins
from (
    select login_id from table1
    union all select login_id from table2
) t
```